# Flutter BoxShadow overlapping siblings

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I'm trying to create a `Row` of containers that all have a `BoxShadow`. The shadows are quite large and therefore span into space that's outside of the parent, so I'm using `clipBehavior: Clip.none` on the parent.

The problem with this is that for each Container within the row it's shadow overlaps into the previous container. I've set some bold colors below to emphasize the issue. As you can see the right-hand side of the previous Container gets the shadow from the next.

[image: BoxShadow overlapping]

Here's my code

```
return SingleChildScrollView(
    clipBehavior: Clip.none,
    scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
    child: Row(
      children: [
        _ShadowedBox(),
        _ShadowedBox(),
        _ShadowedBox(),
      ],
    ),
  );


class _ShadowedBox extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      width: 144,
      child: Column(
        children: [
          SizedBox(
            width: 144,
            height: 144,
            child: Container(
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                              color: Colors.grey,
                              shape: BoxShape.rectangle,
                              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(cardRadius),
                              boxShadow: [
                                BoxShadow(
                                  offset: const Offset(0.0, 6.0),
                                  blurRadius: 38.0,
                                  spreadRadius: 0.0,
                                  color: Colors.red,
                                ),
                                BoxShadow(
                                  offset: const Offset(0.0, 6.0),
                                  blurRadius: 46.0,
                                  spreadRadius: 0.0,
                                  color: Colors.green,
                                ),
                                BoxShadow(
                                  offset: const Offset(0.0, 6.0),
                                  blurRadius: 10.0,
                                  spreadRadius: 0.0,
                                  color: Colors.blue,
                                ),
                              ]
                          ),
                child: ClipRRect(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(cardRadius),
                    child: Image.network("https://via.placeholder.com/400x400.png?text=Coming%20soon", fit: BoxFit.contain)
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Can anyone suggest how to stop the shadow bleeding into the other containers while still being able to show the shadows not being clipped by the parent?

Comment: The important `clipBehavior: Clip.none` is in fact the `Container` of the `_ShadowedBox`. As you can see it in action, its difficult to separate shadow from their widgets as they are drawn at the same time, making it look like a stack. Can't you use a combination of margins and clipBehavior to create space between your elements instead ? Maybe you could share a final design ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay I've tested 2 approaches to fix your issue. As [Wapazz](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3366517/wapazz) said, each of your `Container` is drawn separately with its own shadow so they will overlap.

## Solution #1

A solution could be to apply the shadow effect to your `Row` widget instead of the `_ShadowedBox` but the shadow effect wouldn't be as precise:

### Code

```dart
SingleChildScrollView(
  clipBehavior: Clip.none,
  scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
  child: UnconstrainedBox(
    child: Container(
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        boxShadow: [
          BoxShadow(
            offset: const Offset(0.0, 6.0),
            blurRadius: 38.0,
            spreadRadius: 0.0,
            color: Colors.red,
          ),
          BoxShadow(
            offset: const Offset(0.0, 6.0),
            blurRadius: 46.0,
            spreadRadius: 0.0,
            color: Colors.green,
          ),
          BoxShadow(
            offset: const Offset(0.0, 6.0),
            blurRadius: 10.0,
            spreadRadius: 0.0,
            color: Colors.blue,
          ),
        ],
      ),
      child: Row(
        children: List<Widget>.generate(10, (_) => _ShadowedBox()),
      ),
    ),
  ),
),
```

### Result

[image]

## Solution #2

The other solution I've found would be to use a `Stack` widget with all the shadows rendered in a separate `Row`, so the resulting shadows have the correct shape. The issue with this method being that you need a fixed `width` and `height` for your widget:

### Code

```dart
SingleChildScrollView(
  clipBehavior: Clip.none,
  scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
  child: Stack(
    children: [
      Row(
        children: List<Widget>.generate(
          10,
          (_) => Container(
            margin: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 4),
            width: 144,
            height: 144,
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              shape: BoxShape.rectangle,
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(cardRadius),
              boxShadow: [
                BoxShadow(
                  offset: const Offset(0.0, 6.0),
                  blurRadius: 38.0,
                  spreadRadius: 0.0,
                  color: Colors.red,
                ),
                BoxShadow(
                  offset: const Offset(0.0, 6.0),
                  blurRadius: 46.0,
                  spreadRadius: 0.0,
                  color: Colors.green,
                ),
                BoxShadow(
                  offset: const Offset(0.0, 6.0),
                  blurRadius: 10.0,
                  spreadRadius: 0.0,
                  color: Colors.blue,
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
      Row(
        children: List<Widget>.generate(10, (_) => _ShadowedBox()),
      ),
    ],
  ),
)
```

### Result

[image]

[You can try my full test code on DartPad](https://dartpad.dev/?id=31ac42f8dd0b8473ba0f810065c19146&null_safety=true)

Comment: Thanks, both good solutions. It's just a shame our designers have put this style onto loads of new screens :D